# How to clone a template into multiple parents with same class?

Tags: javascript, node.js, clone

I have a single page application, and when I open multiple windows of the same app and write something it should be copied in all apps. But it only shows it in one window the first one. I get this error: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.

here is my try

```
  let tempHistory = document.querySelector('#tempHistory')
  let cloneHistory = document.importNode(tempHistory.content, true)
  let prevEle = document.querySelector('.fldst')
   document.querySelectorAll('.chat-history').forEach(function (event) { // the new message cannot be inserted to new node parent that it's not the parent
  event.insertBefore(cloneHistory, prevEle)
  document.querySelectorAll('.userHistory').forEach(function (event) {
    event.innerHTML = document.querySelector('.userHistory').value = chatHistory
   })
 })
```

html for the cloned template

```
<div class="chat-history">

              <div class="chat-message clearfix">

               <!-- <img src="http://lorempixum.com/32/32/people" alt="" width="32" height="32"> -->

                <div class="chat-message-content clearfix">

                  <span class="chat-time">13:35</span>

                  <h5>server</h5>

                  <p class="serverRespond"></p>

                </div> <!-- end chat-message-content -->

              </div> <!-- end chat-message -->

              <hr>
           <template id="tempHistory">
              <div class="chat-message clearfix">

                <div class="chat-message-content clearfix">

                  <span class="chat-time">13:37</span>

                  <h5>the user</h5>

                  <p class="userHistory"></p>

                </div> <!-- end chat-message-content -->

              </div> <!-- end chat-message -->
              <hr>
           </template>


              <fieldset class="fldst" >
                    <textarea name="textarea" id="userMessage"
                    rows="2" cols="40" placeholder="Type your message…"></textarea>
                <button id="send" >send</button>
              </fieldset>
```

the message history should be in all chat boxes not just the first one.

[image]